# How can I get programmatic markup into my Angular page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my Angular app (1.4) I have a control in a grid that could be one of several kinds, and so I created a javascript function to do the logic and spit out the markup that should go in.

However it doesn't work correctly. The markup will render, but none of the Angular hooks seem to be in it.  In my limited understanding I think the reason has something to do with this digest cycle/timing.  I also suspect my code ought to be in a directive, but not sure.

I've created a plunk that demo's this problem. https://plnkr.co/edit/nuxFzqN0n6XgSHqmC6jK?p=info  Here is the markup. Visit the plunk to see the js and run it:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div>Button1:    <input type="button" value="Button 1" ng-click="button1click()"/><span ng-show="showButton1Result">BUTTON 1 CLICKED!</span></div>
  <div>Button2:    <span ng-bind-html="button2Markup()"></span></div>
  <div>Button3:    {{ button3Markup }}</div>
</body>
```

You get the idea.  What is the best approach here?

Comment: Would a directive not be the best solution here? If you had a custom button directive you can define different setting to determine button output and then show hide these directives based on parent conditions. The main point I'm trying to make is that you should be allowing directives to compile any html as opposed to a controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatic Angular Templates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951334/programmatic-angular-templates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered elsewhere: [Programmatic Angular Templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951334/programmatic-angular-templates)

A directive is what you want to use:

```
<div>Button 2: <div programatic-button="button2Markup()"></div></div>
<div>Button 3: <div programatic-button="button3Markup"></div></div>

.directive('programaticButton', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var html = scope.$eval(attrs.programaticButton);
      var newElement = $compile(html)(scope);
      element.append(newElement);
    }
  };
});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/YGDOmtdfgQMfy0jnNVI4?p=preview

Comment: So essentially, the scope.$eval evaluates the expression housed in that one attribute (either a function or just the string), and puts it into the html var.  Then the $compile service call compiles that markup so that it gets included in the Angular cycle on the page, attaching the event handlers, etc.  Then you are placing the markup into the element where the directive is called from.  Is that correct?  I'm shaky on the $compile but am reading up on it.  Thanks for the plunk, it's extremely helpful.

Comment: Strangely, when I apply this approach to my real application problem I get the following error: 
    Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '<' not a primary expression at column 1 of the expression [<a class="k-button k-button-icontext" href="/OrderManager/OrderView?OrderId=30789&MarketId=995546" target="_blank" uib-tooltip="View"><i class="fa fa-plane"></i></a>]

Answer (score 1):

As stated, you should be using `directive`. Taking your plunk as starting point, it could be something like the following.

**HTML document**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <my-buttons type="type"></my-buttons>
  <br>
  <my-buttons type="2"></my-buttons>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('plunker', [])
  .directive('myButtons', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        type: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'my-buttons-tpl.html',
      link: function(scope) {
        scope.click = function() {
          scope.clicked = !scope.clicked;
        };
      }
    };
  })
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.type = 1;
  });
```

Where **my-buttons-tpl.html**

```
<span ng-if="type === 1">
  <input type="button" 
         value="Button 1" 
         ng-click="click()">
</span>

<span ng-if="type === 2">
  <input type="button" 
         value="Button 2" 
         ng-click="click()">
</span>

<span ng-show="clicked">button type {{ type }} haz ben clicked</span>
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

I believe `ng-bind-html` doesn't actually bind any of the angular functionality inside the inserted code.

As you can see in [the Angular source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngBind.js#L203) the content is simply placed inside the HTML element, there's nothing else fancy going on.

I think that you should definitely reconsider the use of `ng-bind-html` in this instance and look into [Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) instead